# what the argument attention_size of tf.contrib.seq2seq.AttentionWrapper mean?

Tags: tensorflow, attention-model

There has an argument `anttention_size` in`tf.contrib.seq2seq.AttentionWrapper`, the document says "The basic attention wrapper is tf.contrib.seq2seq.AttentionWrapper. This wrapper accepts an RNNCell instance, an instance of AttentionMechanism, and **an attention depth parameter (attention_size)**;", but what is an attention depth? In the Bahdanau and Luong's paper, I find no attention depth at all, and the source code of the attention mechanism I don't understand clearly. Who can tell me the mean of 'attention_size' and the principle, thank you!

Comment: No one can answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my understanding, the authors of [original paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1409.0473) avoid mixing base theory with implementation details. Thus, they defined attention/context size equal to the encoder hidden size ([image] for bi-directional LSTM) as below:

[image]

[image]

However, if encoder hidden size is too large, computing attention over long sequences may consume significant amount of time and memory.

So, [tensorflow implementation](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/283f03c825312efd3319cb37dc1a412288a536ec/tensorflow/contrib/seq2seq/python/ops/attention_wrapper.py) introduced additional dense attention_layer with tunable **attention_size** option (**attention_layer_size** in later versions) as below:

```
  if attention_layer is not None:
    attention = attention_layer(array_ops.concat([cell_output, context], 1))
  else:
    attention = context
```

**TL;DR;** You can use **attention_size** option to reduce memory consumption of attention mechanism, when encoder hidden size is too large.